# java regular expression detect a double is surrounded by ceil()

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like `"something...ceil(0.9)...something"`.

I'm using Pattern `p = Pattern.compile(".*ceil(.*[0-9]*\\.+[0-9]+)+.*");` to detect if the double is surrounded by `ceil()`. But it does not work. Any one help?

Comment: You need to escape your parentheses, as they are special characters in regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
".*ceil\\(\\d+(.\\d+)?\\).*"
```

Matches numbers like `1`, `738294`, ect (no decimal point) or `2.3` `4432.12634` (number dot number).

If you want to accept numers like `.5`, change the first `+` to a `*`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic one to start with:

```
ceil\\([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*\\)
```

You could be more explicit around defining the number in the brackets but you do need to escape the brackets.

Try using this site for regular expression testing: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Thanks! This problem is kind of hurry. Maybe i will learn regex later.

Answer (score -2):

I don't get; the `Math#ceil(double)` method takes a `double` as an argument but anyway, instead of regex, perhaps you should try simply parsing the argument passed in to the `ceil` method as a `double`; if it throws an exception, it means that it isn't a valid `double`:

```
private boolean validArgument(final String string){
    final int start = string.indexOf("ceil(");
    if(start < 0)
        return false;
    final int end = string.indexOf(')');
    if(end < start || end < 0)
        return false;
    try{
        Double.parseDouble(string.substring(start, end));
        return true;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return false;
    }
}
```

And for usage, it would be like:

`final boolean valid = validArgument("Math.ceil(45.97)");` which should `return` `true`.

Comment: The point of using a regular expression is to avoid having 14 lines of code to do it.

Comment: @Jason I am simply offering another alternative, as regex isn't the only way to do something.

Comment: What I am trying to do is detect if a float is surrounded by a ceil() or a floor(). It does not need to be evaluated. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jason Regex would seem inappropriate in this case because there would be no way to check for the validity of the value (It may exceed the min/max value). At least with the alternative I provided, you would know for sure that the argument would be within bounds.